# Display Multiple Polygon Paths using AGM in Angular 6/7

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, angular6, angular-google-maps

I'm using [Angular Google Maps](https://angular-maps.com/) and `agm-drawing-manager` Drawing Manager using
[AGM-POLYGON](https://stackblitz.com/edit/agm-polygon)

Now having two issues one is not working multiple polygons inside

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [zoom]="zoom" class="cardMapH" #agmMap>
                        <agm-polygon [paths]="pathsOfPoly"></agm-polygon>
                        <agm-drawing-manager (polygonComplete)="polygonCreated($event)" [drawingControl]="managerOptions.drawingControl" [drawingControlOptions]="managerOptions.drawingControlOptions" [polygonOptions]='managerOptions.polygonOptions' [drawingMode]='managerOptions.drawingMode'>
                        </agm-drawing-manager>
                    </agm-map>
```

Not getting co-ordinates after drawing the Polygon

Please help me out to solve these issues, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I did like this and it's working for me

```
<mat-card class="cardMapHcard">
                    <!-- yes {{plraw}} -->
                    <agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [zoom]="zoom" class="cardMapH" #agmMap>
                        <agm-polygon [paths]="pathsOfPol" fillColor="#f44195" fillOpacity=".35" strokeColor="#f44195" *ngFor="let pathsOfPol of pathsOfPolyArr">
                            <!-- <agm-snazzy-info-window [maxWidth]="200" [closeWhenOthersOpen]="true">
                                <ng-template>
                                    My first Snazzy Info Window!
                                </ng-template>
                            </agm-snazzy-info-window> -->
                        </agm-polygon>
                        <agm-drawing-manager (overlayComplete)="overlayCreated($event)" (polygonComplete)="polygonCreated($event)" [drawingControl]="managerOptions.drawingControl" [drawingControlOptions]="managerOptions.drawingControlOptions" [polygonOptions]='managerOptions.polygonOptions' [drawingMode]='managerOptions.drawingMode'>
                        </agm-drawing-manager>
                    </agm-map>
                </mat-card>
            </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
```